# taking average of array

Tags: arrays, perl

I would like to get the average value of 1 or more arrays.

```
my @w = (0,2);
my @x = (1,3);
my @y = (2,2);
my @z = (1,1);
```

such that the average of four arrays above is `(1,2)` since (0+1+2+1)/4 = 1 and (2+3+2+1)/4 = 2.

And the average of `my @r = (3,4,1,4,5)` is `(3/5, 4/5, 1/5, 4/5/, 1)`.

Here's my solution for the first one.

```
my @AoA = (\@w, \@x, \@y, \@z);
my @sums;

foreach my $column(0..$#@w){
    my $average;
    my $size = @w;
    foreach  my  $aref (@AoA){
     $average += ($aref -> [$column]) / $size ;
    }
  push(@sums, $average);
 }
```

this may or may not work. Is there an easier way to do this? Perhaps a function in a module?

My solution for the second one. I think this one's actually easier now that I think about it:

```
my $scalar = @r;
my @new_r;

foreach my $x (@r) { 
    $x = $x / $scalar; 
    push(@new_r, $x);
}
```

again may or may not work. there's probably an easier way to do this.

Comment: Sounds like something you'd use zip for.

Comment: what is zip? is that a function?

Comment: He means List::MoreUtils's `zip`, but it wouldn't help. It's `each_array`/`each_arrayref` could be used, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'sum';

my @w = (0, 2);
my @x = (1, 3);
my @y = (2, 2);
my @z = (1, 1);

my @arrays = \(@w, @x, @y, @z);

my @avg;
for my $i (0..$#w) {
  $avg[$i] =  sum(map $_->[$i], @arrays) / @arrays;
}
print "@avg\n";

my @r = (3, 4, 1, 4, 5);
my @avg_r = map $_ / @r, @r;

print "@avg_r\n";
```

**output**

```
1 2
0.6 0.8 0.2 0.8 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Given

```
use List::Util qw( sum );
sub avg { sum(@_)/@_ }
```

You could use

```
my @w = (0,2);
my @x = (1,3);
my @y = (2,2);
my @z = (1,1);

my @avg = map {
   my $i = $_;
   avg map $_->[$i], \@w, \@x, \@y, \@z
} 0..$#w;
```

Or if you had an AoA:

```
my @matrix = ([0,2], [1,3], [2,2], [1,1]);

my @avg = map {
    my $i = $_;
    avg map $_->[$i], @matrix
} 0..$#{$matrix[0]};
```

As for the "average" of `@r`,

```
my @avg_r = map $_/@r, @r;
```

Comment: thank you, I appreciate it. you and @Borodin essentially have the same solution. though you answered 4 minutes earlier. I don't know who to reward best answer to =x

Comment: Actually, he answered 4 minutes earlier.